# Lightgallery v2 multiple instances

Tags: javascript, lightgallery, htmlcollection, lightgallery-2

This library [has an example](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery#initialize-lightgallery) to build a gallery based on element ID:

```
lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'), {
    plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail],
    speed: 500,
    ... other settings
});
```

I want to build several instances based on a class. I tried to iterate a collection:

```
import lightGallery from 'lightgallery';

let galleries = document.getElementsByClassName('lightbox');

for (const gal of galleries) {
  lightGallery(gal), {
    selector: 'a',
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error (despite the HTML element has an `a` element with `img` inside): `lightGallery :- data-src is not provided on slide item 1. Please make sure the selector property is properly configured.`

How can I build these galleries from an HTML collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating IDs on the way:

```js
let galerias = document.getElementsByClassName('lightbox');

for (let i = 0; i < galerias.length; i++) {

  galerias[i].id = 'gal' + i; // <-------------------- creating IDs here

  lightGallery(document.getElementById('gal' + i), {
    selector: 'a',
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this -- I don't know why this isn't mentioned in the documentation, as the shift from allowing identification via classes seems a step backwards to me and as well, this could potentially conflict with an assigned ID